# ImpactJS moving toward entity

Tags: impactjs

Is there a way to detect whether I am moving towards a particular entity or if I am moving towards a particular entity type?

The issue I am having is to check whether I have hit a fence.  At that point I want to turn around and move in the other direction.  However, the collision is still happening so I can never auto move.

So I need to know if I am heading towards the fence or away from it.

I have tried this but unless I loop through all my fences I can't detect.

```
if (this.distanceTo(EntityRobotFence)< 50)  this.stopMoving();
```

This doesn't work btw.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the following:

`var target = ig.game.getEntitiesByType(EntityRobotFence); // or (EntityRobotFence)[0], etc`

then:

`if (this.distanceTo(target) < 50) this.stopMoving();`

NOTE: `this.distanceTo()` returns the absolute distance in pixels from this entity's center to the other entity's center. So ensure your pixel distance is correct.

Comment: Soooooo, did this work or do you still have psoriasis?